# How to insert footer inside a box

Tags: html, css

I'm new and I'm trying to learn but I have a little question for you all. How can I insert a footer inside the box? Everytime that I insert a new footer go over the nav or outside the box.
Here CSS codes:

```css
#border {
width: 600px;
height: 550px;
border: 7px inset #09223B;
border-radius: 0px 40px 40px 40px;
background: #696969;
}

body {
  background:
     url(wp.jpg)           
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px 28px 0px 0px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #09223B;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Please help

Comment: hi. insert your html here, pls

Comment: `<html>
<title> HG </title>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>
<body>
<center><div id="border">
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>


</div>




</div></center>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

I added a double of the `header (.topnav)` to make the `footer (.bottomnav)`. Used `flex` rules in `#border` selector.

Was it necessary?

```css
body {
  background:
     url(wp.jpg)           
}

#border {
width: 600px;
height: 550px;
border: 7px inset #09223B;
border-radius: 0px 40px 40px 40px;
background: #696969;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px 32px 0px 0px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #09223B;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

/*add*/

.bottomnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 32px 32px;
}

.bottomnav p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/*---*/
```

```html
<body> 
  <center>
  <div id="border"> 
    <div class="topnav">   
      <a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a>   
      <a href="about.html">About</a>   
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>   
    </div>
    <div class="bottomnav">   
      <p>All rights reserved</p>   
    </div>   
  </div>
  </center> 
</body>
```

Comment: I probably explained myself wrong, I needed to write "All rights reserved" in the footer. I have edited the CSS file but the footer appears above the borders. Why?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Was it necessary? If it goes wrong again, show me a screenshot of the desired result, and a screenshot of the problem. And I will do it as you need it.

Comment: Perfect, now it works, thank you so much. Can you tell me what have you changed in the CSS code?

Comment: I marked in the css the rules that I added by making a note - `/*add*/.../*---*/`. And also, I added this code to the html structure - `<div class = "bottomnav"><p> All rights reserved </p></div>`.

Comment: I gave you the answer. If my answer helped you, then mark it as solved by checking the box to the left of my answer. Thanks.